# python: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, class, methods

I have this method in a class

```
class CatList:

    lista = codecs.open('googlecat.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(lista)    
    # parse the list through BeautifulSoup
    def parseList(tag):
        if tag.name == 'ul':
            return [parseList(item)
                    for item in tag.findAll('li', recursive=False)]
        elif tag.name == 'li':
            if tag.ul is None:
                return tag.text
            else:
                return (tag.contents[0].string.strip(), parseList(tag.ul))
```

but when I try to call it like this:

```
myCL = CatList()
myList = myCL.parseList(myCL.soup.ul)
```

I have the following error:

```
parseList() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I tried to add self as an argument to the method but when I do that the error I get is the following:

```
global name 'parseList' is not defined
```

not very clear to me how this actually works.

Any hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You forgot the `self` argument.

You need to change this line:

```
def parseList(tag):
```

with:

```
def parseList(self, tag):
```

You also got a global name error, since you're trying to access `parseList` without `self`.
While you should to do something like:

```
self.parseList(item)
```

inside your method.

To be specific, you need to do that in two lines of your code:

```
 return [self.parseList(item)
```

and

```
 return (tag.contents[0].string.strip(), self.parseList(tag.ul))
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said it's what I tried and i then get:

global name 'parseList' is not defined

Comment: to recursively call it, you would write "self.parselist(tag.ul)"

Comment: @silviolor did you add the "self" to both the function declataion and the call? As a first parameter in the declaration and as "self.parse..." when you call it?