# pass function result as input parameter to a function in class

Tags: python

```
 class main_prg:
      def func():
            # code that generates x and y
            return x,y
      def func1(x):
            #uses the value of x that is returned from func()
           z=x+3
            return z
```

How to pass `x` to `func1()`?

I have tried

```
m=main_prg()
f01,f11 = m.func()
f2 = m.func1(f01)
```

Throws me an error `func1() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: Then we can't reproduce the problem here. This should work as is.

Comment: You are calling `func1(f01)` with one argument and the function is defined with one argument too (`x`), so that error has no sense here.

Comment: if these functions were in a class?Is there any chance to get the above error?

Comment: Post the entire code where that `func1() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` with or without the class and we'll help you out.

Comment: Yes, if you're somehow screwing up how you're calling those functions and an implicit `self` is being passed as well. Show us your *actual* code which *actually* produces this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302436/python-function-takes-exactly-1-argument-2-given)

Comment: that link explains about using a value which is returned in that function itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you your desired output. You have to add `self` to every function inside of a class.

```
class main_prg:
      def func(self):
            # code that generates x and y
            x = 1 # whatever
            y = 2 # whatever
            return x,y
      def func1(self, x):
            #uses the value of x that is returned from func()
            z = 3 # whatever
            return z

m = main_prg()
f01,f11 = m.func()
print f01
print f11
f2 = m.func1(f01)
print f2
```

- `f01`prints `1`
- `f11` prints `2`
- `f2` prints `3`

Comment: How to use the value of x in func1()? Is that self.x? or just x

Comment: If you define it as `x` it will only work inside of the method you defined, in this case `func`. If you define it as `self.x` it will work in all the functions of the class.

Comment: If you're not using `self`, you may want to decorate the method with `@staticmethod` instead.