# TypeError: takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) Python Error

Tags: python

The problem is that i have this function:

```
def fuerza_repulsion(x):
    area = 100 * 100
    k = math.sqrt(area / len(self.grafo[0]))
    return ((k**2 / x) * c2)
```

and in this line

```
f_mod = self.fuerza_repulsion(math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2))
```

i have this error:

> TypeError: fuerza_repulsion() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

How can i fix it?

Comment: Is this function part of a class?  Looks like it,the way you call it....if so, it should have "self" as the first parameter

Comment: In a class, the first argument is the object itself, so when you're calling self.function(x), you're giving two arguments, self and x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302436/python-function-takes-exactly-1-argument-2-given)

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your function is part of a class, in which case the first argument of the function needs to be `self`, the class object itself. (Also, as @SRC pointed out, you generally call class functions 'methods')

So therefore use:

```
def fuerza_repulsion(self, x):
    area = 100 * 100
    k = math.sqrt(area / len(self.grafo[0]))
    return ((k**2 / x) * c2)
```

Comment: I think in this case you should call them `methods`  not functions. No?

Comment: @SRC Yes, I have added that to the original answer. Thanks!